# How to display all my inputs after every command in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem.

I want to display all my records in "view" command, but it only displays the last record.

How do I solve the problem?

Please help me , thank you!

my code:

```
initial_money = int(input('How much money do you have? ')) 

def records():
    return

def add(records):
    records = input('Add an expense or income record with description and amount:\n').split()
    global rec
    rec = records[0]
    global amt
    amt = records[1]
    global initial_money
    initial_money += int(amt)
    
def view(initial_money, records):
    print("Here's your expense and income records:") 
    print("Description          Amount")
    print("-------------------  ------")
    print('{name:<20s} {number:<6s}'.format(name = rec,number = amt))
    print('Now you have {} dollars.'.format(initial_money))

while True:
    command = input('\nWhat do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? ') 
    if command == 'add':
        records = add(records)
    elif command == 'view':
        view(initial_money, records)
```

Output

```
How much money do you have? 100

What do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? add
Add an expense or income record with description and amount:
tomato -50

What do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? add
Add an expense or income record with description and amount:
salary 100

What do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? view
Here's your expense and income records:
Description          Amount
-------------------  ------
salary               100   
Now you have 150 dollars.
```

output I want:

```
-------------------  ------
tomato               -50
salary               100
Now you have 150 dollars.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use a dictionary to hold them instead:

```
initial_money = int(input('How much money do you have? ')) 

mr = {}

def records():
    return

def add(records):
    records = input('Add an expense or income record with description and amount:\n').split()
    global rec
    rec = records[0]
    global amt
    amt = records[1]
    global mr
    global initial_money
    mr[rec] = int(amt)
    initial_money += mr[rec]
    
    
def view(initial_money, records):
    print("Here's your expense and income records:") 
    print("Description          Amount")
    print("-------------------  ------")
    for r,a in mr.items():
      print('{name:<20s} {number:<6s}'.format(name = r,number = str(a)))

    print('Now you have {} dollars.'.format(initial_money))

while True:
    command = input('\nWhat do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? ') 
    if command == 'add':
        records = add(records)
    elif command == 'view':
        view(initial_money, records)
```

Test:

```
How much money do you have? 100         

What do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? add
Add an expense or income record with description and amount:
tomato -50

What do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? add
Add an expense or income record with description and amount:
salary 100

What do you want to do (add / view / delete / exit)? view
Here's your expense and income records:
Description          Amount
-------------------  ------
tomato               -50   
salary               100   
Now you have 150 dollars.
```

Comment: It solves my problem but the total money seems not right.

Comment: Oh it's true now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make records into a list of the records you inserted. Currently you are overwriting it each time you call add.

1. make records an array outside your main loop
2. In your main loop push the results of the call to add into your array In your view function
3. you then need to loop over the array to view all the results.

Also for bonus, stop using global in your add function, It's considered bad form

Comment: Oh really, so I should delete the global and use loop.